# Как задать размер массива с клавиатуры array<int,/*здесь должен быть размер массива*/>arr;

Tags: c++, массивы, библиотеки

Короче, задали лабораторную, вроде легкая и так далее, сделал набросок быстренько, вроде всё готово, а вот преподаватель написал, мол размерность массива нужно задать пользователю с клавиатуры.Ну вот в обычном массиве я бы легко это сделал, но темой являлась библиотека .
Проблема заключается в том, что компилятор требует константные значения.
Вот набросок если что:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(0, "");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
srand(time(NULL));
const int size =10;
array<int,size>arr_int;

cout  << "1-Заданный случайный массив: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//Задание массива рандомными значениями 
{
    arr_int.at(i) = rand() % 1000;//рандомное значение до 1000 каждому элементу массива
    cout << arr_int.at(i) << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl<<"2-Без 5 первых членов массива: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size-5; i++)//Удаление первых 5 членов массива
{
    arr_int.at(i) = arr_int.at(i + 5);
    cout << arr_int.at(i) << " ";
}
cout<<endl<<endl << "3-С добавленными 3 случайными значениями в конец массива: " << endl;
for (int i = size-5; i < size - 5 + 3; i++)//Добавление в конец массива 3 случайных значения
    arr_int.at(i) = rand() % 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 5 + 3; i++)//Вывод массива
    cout << arr_int.at(i)<<" ";
cout << endl<<endl << "4-Сортировка по убыванию: " << endl;
int a;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 5 + 3; i++)//Сортировка
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size - 5 + 3 - 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr_int.at(j) < arr_int.at(j + 1))
        {
            a = arr_int.at(j);
            arr_int.at(j) = arr_int.at(j + 1);
            arr_int.at(j + 1) = a;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < size - 5 + 3; i++)//Вывод массива
    cout << arr_int.at(i) << " ";
cout << endl<<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Одним словом задача --> сделать возможность ввода в консоли пользователем размерности массива из библиотеки .
Язык C++; Спасибо огромное.

Comment: С `std::array` это никак не сделать. Нужен `std::vector`.

Comment: Вывод соответствующих элементов  и  добавление или удаление, совершенно разные действия.

Comment: А если не напрямую, как-либо можно ограничить размер? Переспросил препода, он не оговорился, сказал, что-бы значение можно было задавать пользователем с клавиатуры.И да...Векторы в этой лабе нельзя использовать.

Comment: @ivasam Ну сделайте огромный `std::array`, и используйте только первые `n` элементов. Скорее всего от вас этого ждут. В принципе, еще можно извернуться и сделать это с помощью шаблонов (если максимальный размер массива известен), но это перебор.

Comment: Да, я так и сделал, оказалось, что так и нужно было, т.е. сделать больший массив и использовать часть, спасибо огромное